# Syntax error ?callback=jQuery1113

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to get a basic JSONP query going:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://www.bing.com/',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function(dataWeGotViaJsonp){
                        var text = '';
                        var len = dataWeGotViaJsonp.length;

                        $('#text').html(len);
                    }
                });
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = 'text'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using IE8 and jquery v1.11.3

```
  Syntax error  ?callback=jQuery111309915726215071462_1436849961686&_=1436849961687, line 1 character 1
```

What is this callback? Where is it coming from?

If I change the URL to 'https://www.bing.com/search?q=hello+world'

I get:

```
  Syntax error  search?q=hello+world&callback=jQuery11130544191867791898_1436850255384&_=1436850255385, line 1 character 1
```

Comment: Your browser tried to execute the script received from Bing, but Bing didn't send a script but a webpage. It's like ordering something hot then trying to eat it, belatedly realising you are not in a restaurant but a hardware shop as you are melting your face off with a blowtorch. You can't get JSONP from Bing just by wishful thinking - read about [Bing Search API](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/5BA839F1-12CE-4CCE-BF57-A49D98D29A44).

Comment: @Amadan Ok, your comment is kinda funny, but also a bit unfriendly.

Comment: Sorry about that. Went for funny. Not a bad analogy though - you are trying to consume a response that is not digestible by JS parser. Always check the contents of the URL with, e.g. `curl` or web-browser - if it's not getting JSONP that way, neither is your code (unless they are doing sneaky things specifically to prevent it). As for `?callback=jQuery......`, it is tacked onto your URL by jQuery as a matter of convention; servers that serve JSONP will normally use it to construct your response. So the console is just telling you the URL.

Comment: @Amadan - no worries friendlyness restored! And thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(event){
               if (event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://www.bing.com/',
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        success: function(dataWeGotViaJsonp){
                            var text = '';
                            var len = dataWeGotViaJsonp.length;

                            $('#text').html(len);
                        }
                    });
                })
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id = 'text'></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

// Use event.preventDefault.

Answer (score 0):

Change  `dataType: 'jsonp'` to `dataType: 'text'`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Unless you've run this code and it doesn't work, that's my answer and I'm sticking to it!